# cambiar de una activity a otra. Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio, activity

```
public void nuevapartida_button (View view){
    Intent nuevapartida_button = new Intent(this, ActivityDeNuevaPartida.class);
    startActivity(nuevapartida_button);
}

    final Button nuevapartidaButton = findViewById(R.id.nuevapartida_button);
    nuevapartidaButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        }
    });
```

Comment: cual es el problema en realidad? alli tienes un metodo que te hace un intent ya

Comment: No se entiende de que va el código, además alguien ya pregunto con un código similar a este.
https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/232826/cambiar-de-una-activity-a-otra-android-studio/232831#232831

Answer (score -2):

El método **nuevapartida_button** que tienes hecho abre el activity de **ActivityDeNuevaPartida**. Luego en el método **onClick** del botón **nuevapartidaButton** lo tienes vacio. Pero si llamas al método que creaste arriba **nuevapartida_button** hará lo que deseas.

```
public void nuevapartida_button(View view) {
    Intent nuevapartida_button = new Intent(this, ActivityDeNuevaPartida.class);
    startActivity(nuevapartida_button);
}

final Button nuevapartidaButton = findViewById(R.id.nuevapartida_button);
nuevapartidaButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
         nuevapartida_button(v);
    }
});
```

Comment: y esto que es?...

Comment: [Te podrían votar negativamente porque no esperaste a entender la pregunta antes de contestar.](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3217/342)

Comment: Oh, puede ser cierto. Gracias! @element

Comment: No se entiende el tema, pusiste sólo código sin explicar de qué trata, así no conseguirás respuestas.

Comment: @GermánMartínez yo no fui el que puso la pregunta, solo la respondí, aunque si debía haber puesto una explicación en la respuesta. Gracias!